# Java Help - Making a 'sweeper' game

Tags: java

Our assignment is to make a simple 'pac-man' game that just eats the trash inside a rectangle. The trash being "*". 
My code so far:

```
public class Sweeper 
{    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        //************************************************************
        // Variable set up
        int sy = 10, sx= 10; // Box size
        int x= 5, y= 5; // Start point
        int maxmc = 8; // Max distance moving
        char [] [] env = new char[sy][sx];
        int right = sx - 2, top = sy - 2, left = sx - (right + 1) , bottom = sy - (top + 1);
        //************************************************************

        //************************************************************
        // Filling the grid with Stars
        for(int i=0; i<sy;i++)
        {
            for(int j =0; j < sx; j++)
            {
                env[i][j] = '*';
            }
        }
        //************************************************************

        int mc = 0, direction = 0, count =  (right * top);
        // The actual game
        while(count != 0)
        {
            direction = (int)(Math.random() * 3);
            // Display
            //System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n");
            for(int i = 0; i < sy; i++)
            {
                for(int j= 0; j< sx; j++)
                {
                    System.out.print(env[i][j]);

                }

                System.out.println();
            }

            System.out.println("\n\n\n");

            Thread.sleep(700);

            System.out.println(direction);

            if((x <= right && x >= left && y <= top && y >= bottom))
            {
                if(env[x][y] == ' ')
                {
                    // RIGHT
                    if(direction == 0)
                    {
                        env[y][x] = '@';
                        x--;
                        env[y][x+2] = ' ';
                    }
                    // left
                    else if(direction == 1)
                    {
                        env[y][x] = '@';
                        x++;
                        env[y][x-2] = ' ';
                    }
                    // TOP
                    else if(direction ==2)
                    {
                        env[y][x] = '@';
                        y--;
                        env[y+2][x] = ' ';
                    }
                    // bottom
                    else if(direction ==3)
                    {
                        env[y][x] = '@';
                        y++;
                        env[y-2][x] = ' ';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(direction == 0)
                    {
                        env[y][x] = '@';
                        x--;
                        env[y][x+2] = ' ';
                    }
                    // left
                    else if(direction == 1)
                    {
                        env[y][x] = '@';
                        x++;
                        env[y][x-2] = ' ';
                    }
                    // TOP
                    else if(direction ==2)
                    {
                        env[y][x] = '@';
                        y--;
                        env[y+2][x] = ' ';
                    }
                    // bottom
                    else if(direction ==3)
                    {
                        env[y][x] = '@';
                        y++;
                        env[y-2][x] = ' ';
                    }
                    // Keeps track of the trash
                    count--;
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

My problem:
It copies the '@' and stops moving sometimes. 
Im trying to make it move aorund until all the inside 8x8 star symbols are all gone.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in your IDE debugger? That is the place to start.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

Just to clean your code: your moving algorithm is duplicated the (4 `if/else` statements) . You need to put only `count--` in a  `if(! env[x][y] == ' ')` statement.

For your problem: your badly checkin your bounds condition, you do

```
env[y][x] = '@';
x--;
env[y][x+2] = ' ';
```

But if  `x=1`, then after the code it's 0, and because you have

```
        if((x <= right && x >= left && y <= top && y >= bottom))
```

With `x=0` and `right=0`, then it never enter the statement, `count` cannot change, and it loops infinetly.